# RxJS - Observable is not emitting value with .next() on first call

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

I'm struggling a bit with RxJS. I have 3 Observables. First Observable emits a single value on document click and immediately completes (intentionally). Second Observable listens to first$ Observable and maps those values. Finally, the third Observable concats second$ Observable with the last element emitted by first$.

It's much easier to understand it by looking at the code:

```
const somethingHappened = true;

const first$ = Observable.create(observer => {
  document.addEventListener('click', e => {
    console.log('document clicked!')
    if (somethingHappened) {
      observer.next(5)
      observer.complete()
    } else {
      observer.next(5)
    }
  })
})

const second$ = first$.pipe(
  map((a: number) => a * 10),
)

const third$ = second$.pipe(
  concat(first$.pipe(last(), map(element => console.log('last element:', element)))),
)

third$.subscribe()
```

demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-apcjsh (click on the document and look at the console)

What is happening is really interesting actually. After first click on the document, I expect third$ observable to be completed, therefore, the `console.log('last element:', element)`  should fire. Instead, only the `console.log('document clicked!')` fires!

After next click on the document `console.log('document clicked!')` fires twice and `console.log('last element:', element)` once.

Can someone explain to me what is going on there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> After first click on the document, I expect `third$` observable to be completed

In order for `third$` to complete, both `second$` and all of the arguments to `concat()` also need to complete. The argument to `concat()`:

```
first$.pipe(last(), map(element => console.log('last element:', element)))
```

is a brand new Observable that is only subscribed to **after `second$` completes** - so you end up with a second click handler being installed on your document.

If you add some logging output to your Observable function:

```
const first$ = Observable.create(observer => {
    console.log('subscribed', Date.now()); // Add this
    document.addEventListener('click', e => {
      ...
```

You will see two log 'subscribed' messages. Once when the page loads (after `$third.subscribe()` is called), and once again after you click the document the first time (when `concat()` subscribes to its argument).